# Generate CSV file with header at second row and string at first row in dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to generate a CSV output with Headers in the second row then headers in the second row and the data starts from the third row. How to generate this using DataWeave 2.0.

Below is CSV sample file which I want to generate

[image]

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. CSV is a TEXT format, you should show a textual example of the expected output.

Comment: The explanation is not fully clear. Do you want "UTF-8" to be in the first 'cell' of the first line?

Comment: Yes I want "UTF-8" to be in the first cell of the first line.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the expected output by treating the output as a string, and concatenating the first row manually with the output of writing the CSV transformation as a string. The write() function can be used to do that.

```js
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
"UTF-8\n" ++ write(payload, "application/csv")
```